# d3.js store pixel coordinates of circles appended haphazardly from force simulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simplified visual where I'm trying to draw bezier lines from a bunch of small circles (on the right) to a big circle (on the left). Snippet in progress:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var data = d3.range(200).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie', top:false, link:'2019'} });

data.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.x = 900;
  //d.y = 100;
  d.y = 200
});

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
return 900;
  }).strength(0.4))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
//return 100;
return 200;
  }).strength(0.1))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(4))
  .stop();

simulation.tick(75);
console.log(data)
var circles = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
return 2;
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
return d.y;
  })
  .style('fill', "#003366")
  .on('click', function(d) {
return console.log(d3.select(this).datum());
  });

var topData = [
  {year:'2019', top:true}
];

graphGroup.selectAll(null)
.data(topData)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('cx', 200)
.attr('cy', 200)
.attr('r', 20)
.style('fill', "#003366");


  var topCircles = d3.selectAll('circle').filter(function(d) {return d.top == true}).data();
  var bottomCircles = d3.selectAll('circle').filter(function(d) {return d.top == false}).data();
  console.log(topCircles)
  var topLinks = topCircles.map(function(d,i) {
return {source: [200, 200], link:d.year}
  });

  var bottomLinks = bottomCircles.map(function(d,i) {
return {target: [d3.select(this).datum().cx, d3.select(this).datum().cy], link:d.year}
  });

  var multiLinkData = topLinks.map(t1 => ({...t1, ...bottomLinks.find(t2 => t2.link === t1.link)}));

  console.log(multiLinkData)


  var link = d3.linkHorizontal();


  graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(multiLinkData)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  //.join("path")
  .attr("d", link)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  //.style('stroke', function(d) {return colorMap[d.applied]})
  .attr("stroke", "#d9d9d9");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

So none of the lines are appended yet; error reads can't read `cx` of undefined on this line:

```
  var bottomLinks = bottomCircles.map(function(d,i) {
    return {target: [d3.select(this).datum().cx, d3.select(this).datum().cy], series:d.name}
  });
```

But as I recall, this is the only way to retrieve pixel coordinates of svgs. Since they are appended from a swarm simulation, the exact location of each circle can't be pre-calculated. Thus, I was thinking it appropriate to place my source/target logic for the bezier lines after the circle appends, then I can grab the actual pixel coordinates after the simulation spits out its rendering.

### Question

What could be the flaw in my ad hoc coordinate generating, or is there a simpler way to refer to those circle center points given my snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for an interesting visualization!

You had the right idea, but actually, you could have retrieved those values in a much easier way since you had already set `x` and `y` in place with `forEach()` towards the beginning of your code. So there is no need to creep every thing and look up individual `cx`s and `cy`s. All you need is this to get the right values into `multiLinkData`:

```
var bottomLinks = bottomCircles.map(function(d,i) {
  return {target: [d.x, d.y], link:d.link}
});


  var multiLinkData = bottomLinks.map(t1 => ({...t1, ...topLinks.find(t2 => t2.link === t1.link)}));
```